# Setting back and font colour for CComboBoxEx items

Tags: mfc, comboboxex

I have read up on a few articles about `CComboBox` and changing font properties by using owner draw.

But I am using a `CComboBoxEx`. At the moment I can set the images etc.:

```
COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem;

cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_IMAGE | CBEIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | CBEIF_TEXT | CBEIF_LPARAM;
if (psReference != nullptr) // AJT v18.1.6
    cmbItem.iImage = ImageType::kReferenced;
else
    cmbItem.iImage = pEntry->IsCircuitVisit() || pEntry->IsSpecialEvent() ? ImageType::kSpecialEvent : ImageType::kNoEvent;
cmbItem.iSelectedImage = cmbItem.iImage;
cmbItem.iItem = i;
cmbItem.pszText = strDateText.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);
cmbItem.lParam = (LPARAM)pEntry;
strDateText.ReleaseBuffer();

m_cbDates.InsertItem(&cmbItem);
```

It all works fine. But I would like to set certain items with a different colour background, and or possibly change the text colour.

Is owner draw still the only way?